# How much does it cost to launch one site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, company

One of the most appreciable approach of Stack Exchange I like is giving opportunity to group of people to gather and build communities (passionate about specific area of expertise) as a part of Stack Exchange Network!

Many Area51 proposals are created per week and hardly few of them pass from definition phase (That's working as expected). However, I think averagely 1 site is started as a beta at every two months. And debate for graduating the site have been happening occasionally.

Stack Exchange network is network of 170+ sites and is still growing! It would definitely be a nice thing to grow for the Stack Exchange, however, another side of coin is also coming in my mind that is maintenance and operating effort/cost Stack Exchange needs to put for launching sites.

How much maintenance or operating effort /cost does Stack Exchange require to put for launching a site in first of all in the beta phase? I assume there can be technical and database etc. Then what extra effort requires for a final launch (considering design independent)? I assume updating some features and moderator election; plus, community managers may require to put some efforts whenever any major changes happen in the site. And finally effort requires for designing graphics.

I understand that it may not be possible to answer all the questions but if some overview is provided, it would be useful for better understanding economical approach.

<sup>Some users worthlessly inquire or complain e.g. why his/her proposal deleted/closed and why is my site not considered for graduation but I think they should understand the feasibility and usefulness or worthiness of launching the site.</sup>

Comment: I can't imagine the effort would raise much with a new site, given they have to operate SO as well which is huge (really huge) compared to most of the other sites in the network. Adding a site is just a new database and website in IIS, some dns entries and it's running.

Comment: The biggest cost would be staff hours. But since the changes to the Area51 process there's only been one launched site. Who knows if there'll be another.

Comment: Why is the cost of a single event (launch) all you're asking about here? The cost of long-term support for a site can be significantly higher than the single-day cost of launching.

Comment: @Catija True. I didn't consider that while asking the question (probably 2.5 years ago)